# Como unir consultas en usando eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

¿Cómo puedo unir consultas usando eloquent?.
Consultas de este tipo:

```
SELECT persona.*, usuario.*, rol_usuario.* , municipio.* FROM persona
                INNER JOIN usuario ON persona.persona_id = usuario.usuario_persona_id
                INNER JOIN rol_usuario ON usuario.usuario_id = rol_usuario.rol_usuario_usuario_id
                INNER JOIN municipio ON persona.persona_municipio_id = municipio.municipio_id
```

Answer (score 2):

En Eloquent se llaman relaciones.

Teniendo en cuenta que es una consulta sencilla la que se muestra en el ejemplo, sería algo así, asumiendo que se hayan creado los modelos y relaciones correctamente:

```
Persona::with(['usuario.rolUsuario', 'municipio'])->get();
```

Eager loading es lo que permite «precargar» las relaciones para evitar posibles inconvenientes de desempeño.

---

En la documentación se encuentra toda la información para crear los modelos y relaciones respectivos: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships